# scala underscore parameter not acting as named parameter, in spark map reduce

Tags: scala, apache-spark, lambda, encoder

I see some difference when using underscore parameter or named parameter in spark map function.

look at this code (executed in spark-shell):

```
var ds = Seq(1,2,3).toDS()
ds.map(t => Array("something", "" + t)).collect // works cool
ds.map(Array("funk", "" + _)).collect // doesn't work
```

the exception I get for the not working line is:

> error: Unable to find encoder for type stored in a 
>   Dataset.  Primitive types (Int, String, etc) and Product types (case 
>   classes) are supported by importing spark.implicits._  Support for 
>   serializing other types will be added in future releases.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That's because the expansion of:

```
ds.map(Array("funk", "" + _)).collect
```

Doesn't work as you think. It expands to:

```
ds.map(Array("funk", ((x: Any) => "" + x))).collect
```

The `_` in your array creation expands to a function. According to the documentation of DataSets, functions are not supported.

If we take a minimal reproduce:

```
val l = List(1,2,3)
val res = l.map(Array("42", "" + _))
```

And see the typer expansion (`scalac -Xprint:typer`), you can see:

```
def main(args: Array[String]): Unit = {
  val l: List[Int] = scala.collection.immutable.List.apply[Int](1, 2, 3);
  val res: List[Object] = 
    l.map[Object, List[Object]]
    (scala.Predef.wrapRefArray[Object]
      (scala.Array.apply[Object]("42", ((x$1: Any) => "".+(x$1))
```

If we isolate the specific relevant part, we can see that:

```
(x$1: Any) => "".+(x$1)
```

Is the expansion that happens inside the array creation.

Comment: @Alexey Thanks! Fixed.